# Is it possible to programatically move an embedded chart in a spreadsheet to its own sheet (tab in a spreadsheet)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to programatically move an embedded chart in a spreadsheet to its own sheet (tab in a spreadsheet)?

Or create the chart in its own sheet?

I know it is possible to do it manually, so it should also be possible to do it with a script?

Answer (score 2):

You can use next method in the `Spreadsheet` class: [`.moveChartToObjectSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#movecharttoobjectsheetchart):

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var chart = sheet.newChart().setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0).build();
sheet.insertChart(chart);
var objectSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().moveChartToObjectSheet(chart);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include an example or unofficial documentation for this undocumented method?

Comment: you can now record macros in gsheets.  record a macro of moving a chart to standalone sheet and you will see this method called out in the macro.  Thats all I know about it.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can set the chart parameters and set the chart to new sheet.

```
var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('- source sheet name-');
 var range = sSheet.getRange("A1:B8");
 var chart = sSheet.getCharts()[0];
 chart = chart.modify()
     .addRange(range)
     .setOption('title', 'Updated!')
     .setOption('animation.duration', 500)
     .setPosition(2,2,0,0)
     .build();
var dSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('-sheet name-');
 sSheet.removeChart(chart);
 dSheet.insertChart(chart);
```

You can also refer to this [page](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/06/programmatically-managing-charts-in.html) for more details.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but this code is moving the chart from one sheet to another. What I want is a chart with its own sheet.

Comment: What do you mean by its own sheet? Like new sheet in the existing spreadsheet? For this you can simply create a new sheet and copy that chart. Refer to this page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(Integer,Object)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mSdBMr1CMetfry5NJTJiNcLpq_xwGqZlV6AosdWcakU/edit?usp=sharing